# Возможно ли создать свой модуль для Python?

Tags: python, модули

Если да, то просьба вкратце рассказать как, и по возможности дать ссылку на существующие материалы.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаешь файл с именем своего модуля. (пусть будет mymodule)
2. Заполняешь его функциями, объектами своего модуля.
3. Помещаешь его в одну папку с main.py
4. В main.py пишешь `import mymodule`
5. И юзаешь в своем коде его функции, объекты и т.д.:
   `mymodule.your_fuction()` например.